# Find smallest unused number SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query to find the smallest unused number. The query I used before took the max number +1 from the database, but I want to change this query to get the smallest unused number.

To get the max number +1 is use this code (which works):

```
public void getType()
{
        String query = "SELECT Max(IncIncidentType) FROM IncIncidentType;";    
        cmd.Connection = SqlServerConnection.sqlConnection;
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        SqlServerConnection.sqlConnection.Open();
        String maxTypeId = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        SqlServerConnection.sqlConnection.Close();

        if (maxTypeId == "")
        {
            incidentTypeId.Text = "0";
        }
        else
            incidentTypeId.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(maxTypeId) + 1).ToString(); 
}
```

I have found some possible answers like

```
SELECT TOP 1 
   t1.Id + 1 
FROM 
   table t1
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table t2 WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id + 1)
ORDER BY 
   t1.Id
```

When I try to change this query to work for my database I get a wrong id (the id I get is already in use). How can I make this query work for my database?

Here some pics of my database structure

[image]

http://i59.tinypic.com/1jxjdy.png

In the situation in the picture below I want to get back 0.

[image]

http://i58.tinypic.com/2s141n6.png

Comment: I hope you don't use this to generate unique IDs. Because this won't work in a multi-user environment.

Comment: What's a better way to make it work then?

Comment: Use a sequence or an identity column. Everything else is either broken or won't scale with parallel inserts. The *only* (really: **only**) situation where something like this is required if you really, really need a gapless numbering, e.g. for legal reasons.  But you will *have* to lock your table before you retrieve the id.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you give an sequence example for a situation like this? Or point me to an sequence example? And how to lock the table? Im not that good with SQL.

Comment: Sure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can I make use of the c# sql transaction class to lock the database?

Comment: I don't know c# but you should not lock the *database*, you should only lock the *table*.